# Chess, preventing a piece from jumping over pieces when going diagonally

Tags: java, chess

hope you guys are doing fine.

I've been trying to code a chess engine in the last two days, i have problem i can't seem to solve, i have this code below that works perfecally fine, the piece goes diagonally in all the 2D space limited in the board (note that the board is an 8*8 2D array), the problem is i can't figure out how to prevent a piece from jumping over other pieces when going diagonally

here is the method:

```
    /**
 * y = abs(x)
 * y = -abs(x)
 * programming these 2 functions will let the piece go diagonally in all directions.
 *@param pieceX: current X coordinates of the piece
 * @param pieceY : current Y Coordinates of the piece
 * @param board: Board instance to get the locations of all the pieces
 * @return legal movements
 */
protected int[][] diagonalMove(int pieceX, int pieceY, Board board)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> legalXMovements = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> legalYMovements = new ArrayList<>();

    //cartesian plane with a size of 8*8.
    for (int x = 7; x > -8; x--)
    {
        for (int y = 7; y > -8; y--)
        {
            //function 1: y = abs(x) and y > 0: Math.abs(x) == Math.abs(y)
            //function 2: y = -abs(x) : y == -Math.abs(x)
            if (Math.abs(x) == Math.abs(y) || y == -Math.abs(x))
            {
                //prevent OutOfBounds at any case.
                if (pieceX + x >= 0 && pieceX + x < 8)
                {
                    if (pieceY + y >= 0 && pieceY + y < 8)
                    {
                        //make sure that the piece doesn't eat his allies

                        //if Tile is empty.
                        if (board.getTile(pieceX + x, pieceY + y).checkIsEmpty())
                        {
                            legalXMovements.add(pieceX + x);
                            legalYMovements.add(pieceY + y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if enemy.
                            if (color != board.getTile(pieceX + x, pieceY + y).getPiece().getColor())
                            {
                                legalXMovements.add(pieceX + x);
                                legalYMovements.add(pieceY + y);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Chess, preventing a piece from jumping over pieces when going diagonally
    int[][] finalLegalMovements = new int[legalXMovements.size()][2];
    for (int x = 0; x < legalXMovements.size(); x++)
    {
        finalLegalMovements[x][0] = legalXMovements.get(x);
        finalLegalMovements[x][1] = legalYMovements.get(x);
    }


    return finalLegalMovements;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

output:
[image]

Comment: You have to check for each tile in the path if it is empty. Simple as that.

Comment: thanks for replying!, i know i need to check each tile but then what, the problem is how to implement the solution in the  code above? thanks again

Comment: Build a loop that goes from the starting space to the target space, ignoring those two, and check if all of the spaces are empty. But tbh I would code the whole thing differently (in fact, I have done so before).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code I once wrote, which works just fine, but uses a different architecture from yours. Anyway, it might help you come up with your own solution.

```
    else if((piece == 'B') || (piece == 'b')){
        
        //Check if deltaX and deltaY are equal
        if(Math.abs(move.getFromX()-move.getToX()) == Math.abs(move.getFromY() - move.getToY())){
            //check the directions
            int directionX = 1;
            if(move.getToX() < move.getFromX())
                directionX = -1;
            
            int directionY = 1;
            if(move.getToY() < move.getFromY())
                directionY = -1;
            
            // Check if everything is free
            int y = move.getFromY();
            for(int x = move.getFromX() + directionX; x != move.getToX(); x += directionX){
                y += directionY;
                
                if(position.getPieceAt(x, y) != ' ')
                    //A piece is in the way -> move illegal!
                    return false;
                
            }
            
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Note that I wrote this in 2009, it is not good code, it could be structured far better and has stylistic problems. But the maths are solid.

Comment: Thanks for your time!, yes your code below is very helpful (and pretty much less gory than mine xD), i'm thinking about refactoring this method if i have to, and your code gave me some ideas, thanks again!

Comment: Well, I basically threw out my first five attempts at implementing the rules of chess because they were way messier than this, and my first draft was definitely very gory - but it definitely helped me learn a lot.